# Consuming JSON data in iPhone using iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I consume this JSon data in iOS 5

```
({assets = ( { identity = 34DL3611;}, {identity = 34GF0512;}, {identity = 34HH1734;}, {identity = 34HH1736;}, {identity = 34YCJ15;} );

identity = DEMO;})
```

getting this data on console through this call

```
    id list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

NSLog(@"VLIST: %@", list);
```

Now I have got the data in exact JSON format after using encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, I want to use native jsonserializer of iOS 5

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

the JSON data is:

```
[{"assets":[{"identity":"34DL3611"},{"identity":"34GF0512"},{"identity":"34HH1734"},{"identity":"34HH1736"},{"identity":"34YCJ15"}],"identity":"DEMO"}]
```

Now how can I get this data, so that I would get assets array values and populate them in table and get the value of identity(which is DEMO) to use it as a header.

thanx

Comment: Whatever this is, it's not JSON. I guess you have to write your own parser.

Comment: looks like the output of a call to `[NSDictionary description]` to me

Comment: i have added the code through which I am getting this data

Comment: @OmerKhan: If this is the output of `[NSDictionary description]`: Is this the format how the data is transmitted or is just a sample to illustrate the structure of the data? Do you want to read to data from a file or from a web service?

Comment: I have added the exact JSON data in my question please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are able to successfully parse the JSON data and now would like to know how you can access the data. The parsed JSON data is either a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` instance containing `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc. instances.

From your sample data, it looks as if your data is heavily nested. (The purpose isn't quite clear.) It's an array containing a dictionary containing an array containing a dictionary.

You could access it like this:

```
NSArray list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSDictionary dict = [list objectAtIndex: 0];
NSArray assets = [dict objectForKey: @"assets"];
NSString identity = [dict objectForKey: @"identity"];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < [assets count]; index++) {
    NSDictionary itemDict = [assets objectAtIndex: index];
    NSString itemIdentity = [itemDict objectForKey: @"identity"];
}
```

Comment: codo please see the question I have corrected it ... now please guide me

Comment: @OmerKhan: Thanks for adding the JSON data. It confirms that I correctly understood the structure of the received data. So my answer is valid as it is.

Answer (score 1):

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) has better performance and is very easy to add to your project (2 files) and easy to use.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myJsonString objectFromJSONString];
```

When I'm working with json data, I always run it through an [online json formater, parser and validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).  This lets me know that the json is valid and improves my understanding of the data.

Answer (score 0):

[SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) is another option to consider.

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary* dict = [parser objectFromString:jsonString];
[parser release];
```

It's [API](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/) is very handy and formatted very much like Apple's Class References.